# How to add a new attribut in your model Class in asp MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created my model but whem I want to add a new attribut, appears always this error :

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1519  Invalid token '}' in class, struct, or interface member declaration CarManagement   C:\Users\aganfoud\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CarManagement\CarManagement\Models\Voiture.cs   33  Active
```

this my model :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CarManagement.Models
{
    public class Voiture
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]

        public string Marque { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]

        public string Modele { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true) Display(Name = "Construction Date")
        DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ConstructionDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 99999)]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public string Color { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
    }
}
```

the error appears when I want to add the attribut **Color**, without this attribut, he works perfectly

Comment: try to put the attributes above the properties

Comment: You're also missing a ',' in the combined attributes on ContructinDate. Could be a copy/post error.

Comment: Thanks, it works without this ',' I dont know what s the problem, coz I have an exception now after puting the properties above :
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 1):

Attributes always go **above** method or property declarations. They apply to what comes next.

Your last set of attributes is not followed by a method or property declaration, so the compiler can't tell what it should apply to, hence the error.

So make it like this:

```
public class Voiture
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Marque { get; set; }

    ...

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ah ok, thanks for answering me, I understand but what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Put the Attribute lines above the Color property, and do the same for all others to make sure they apply correctly!

Comment: I did it but I have know an Exception :
 An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: That is unrelated, you'll need to post a new question to get answers for that.

Answer (score 0):

attributes go above the props not below

```
[Required]
[StringLength(30)]
public string Color { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did it but I have know an Exception :
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: i guess you are using code first so then you need to update database as well

Comment: enable migrations and update database link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I tried but it didnt works because of one or more Context was found in the assembly "ProjectContext"

Comment: So I typed in PM
 "Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext."
 but it appears this time :
Enable-Migrations : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext.'.
At line:1 char:1